# Parse error: Unexpected character Angular 4

Tags: angular

I have an object like this:

```
persona = {
...
edadNiño = 9
}
```

And I want to bind it like this:

```
<input type="number"  name="edadNiño" [(ngModel)] = "persona.edadNiño">
```

But I get the error:

```
compiler.es5.js:1694 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token 'Lexer Error: Unexpected character [ñ] at 
column 77 in expression [persona.edadNiño]'
```

Does anyone know how can I solve this?
Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

Just try replacing ur component code with the following code coz I think a special character '~' is causing the issue for you

```
persona = {
      edadNino = 9
    }
```

And in HTML just do the following

```
<input type="number"  name="edadNino" [(ngModel)] = "persona.edadNino">
```

Comment: Yes but happens the same with the nickflynn's advide: I  serialize that object to use it with an API, and it requires the info like that. I know I can make a method or something to do it "manually", but I don't know if I can do any set up

Answer (score 0):

I would replace the `ñ` with `n` in `edadNiño`.

It looks like there is an open issue with non-UTF characters:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/517

Comment: Yes but the thing is that what I do is to serialize that object to use it with an API, and it requires the info like that. I know I can make a method or something to do it "manually", but I don't know if I can do any set up